Documentary about singer from Detroit
What is the name of the documentary about a singer from Detroit, who sold very few records in the US but unbeknownst to him, he was a big success in South Africa?
In South Africa he was assumed to be dead, and the documentary is focused on finding out how he supposedly died. 
Spoiler: 

 It then transpires he was not dead, and ends up becoming famous and
 performing in South Africa, and after the release of the documentary,
 globally.


You're looking for Searching for Sugar Man, from 2012.

In the early 1970s, Sixto Rodriguez was a Detroit folksinger who had a short-lived recording career with only two well received but non-selling albums. Unknown to Rodriguez, his musical story continued in South Africa where he became a pop music icon and inspiration for generations. Long rumored there to be dead by suicide, a few fans in the 1990s decided to seek out the truth of their hero's fate. What follows is a bizarrely heartening story in which they found far more in their quest than they ever hoped, while a Detroit construction laborer discovered that his lost artistic dreams came true after all.

